# I can't post pictures because I'm a newcomer?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I can't post any pictures because I'm a newcomer. It says that I need at least 10 reputation to do so. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have 11 rep now, so you should be able to post images!

Answer (score 9):

Post some high quality answers or questions without images or links and gain reputation. It takes 1 good answer or 2 good questions for you to gain the required reputation to post an image.

Comment: Unfortunately, users with low reputation points are not allowed to upload pictures, another rule that I think should be changed.... At least a "senior" user should be able to temporarily grant a new user access to upload a picture to explain a situation, and then have to verify the contribution before the picture is made public... This would block spam, since no senior user would jeopardise his or her reputation, whilst still allowing new users to fully participate (under guidance).